# Java Past Paper - Is it just me or wording of this switch statement q is making it unsolvable?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have been revising for my exam and I have found a question in one of my past papers which (at least to me) seem unsolvable. I will have to attach it as a picture because it has been scanned and saved as set of images.

[image]

You can't tell the output of this code when taking into consideration values from sub questions because no actual parameter is being passed to the method and so into the switch statement. Is my understanding correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: @assylias just re-read the question :(

Comment: I imagine this is a typo from your professor, or there is some key piece of information missing from this question that was defined at the beginning of the exam.

Comment: @Reimeus Well then you still can't decide because you don't know the original value of `value`...

Comment: This is obviously a case of typo(s) in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree - without knowing what the value of num is, you can't decide what the output is. Maybe there is a typo and the method was supposed to be:

```
public static void compute(int value) {
    switch(value) {...}
}
```

in which case the answer should take into account the fact that if you change `value` in one of the case statements, the original value is used to decide if the other case statements should be executed (in other words, only one case statement can be executed).

Comment: That's exactly what I thought however I wanted to ask just to make sure I wasn't missing something trivial. Thanks.